# Linking simple link to tab from another page

Tags: jquery, css

I have links on one page that is called **people.html**

```
<a href="single.html"><h3>Name1</h3></a>
<a href="single.html"><h3>Name2</h3></a>
<a href="single.html"><h3>Name3</h3></a>
<a href="single.html"><h3>Name4</h3></a>
```

When I click on one of this links I want to open (make active) corresponding tab that is on another page called **single.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left sideways">
    <li class="active"><a href="#nameOne" data-toggle="tab" >Name1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nameTwo" data-toggle="tab">Name2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nameThree" data-toggle="tab">Name3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nameFour" data-toggle="tab">Name4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: use `target='_blank'` attribute in `a` tag

Comment: maybe just `<a href="single.html#nameOne"><h3>Name1</h3></a>` etc..

Comment: Surely that wouldn't make the tab active, only navigate to the tab if it's already active? To make the make tab active you need a global variable that sets the tab you want to be active and then in the next page uses that variable to activate the tab.

Comment: No, I don't want only to open page in new tab. When a link is clicked one from nav-tabs from another page should be active. So if I click on Name2 link, nav tab with href="nameTwo" should be active.

Comment: @Marek, that is not working I tried it few times

Comment: then on the page `single.html` handle fragment identifier by script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have clicked any anchor tag and now in your URL the links appears like this with the tab you have clicked.

```
"www.xyz.com/page#tab1";
```

Now on load of the page get the URL

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Get the tab to make active from url link.

```
 var activeTab = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
```

Remove old active tab class

```
 $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active in");
```

Add active class to new tab

```
$("#" + activeTab).addClass("active in");
```

Or directly open tab after getting activeTab.

```
$('a[href="#'+ activeTab +'"]').tab('show')
```

Comment: Hey Anil, I'm still having a small issue with this anchor linking. Problem is when another page is loaded, because it is always showing first (deault) image for half of second and then it is loading tab. Hope I was clear.